# How to get support from GitHub?

Tags: repository, github, git

To get this out of the way, I'm an established GitHub user.  My configs are set and certs are in place.  I can continue to push, pull, clone from GitHub normally.

I created a new repo on the site (a private repo within my organization) about 2 days ago.  (Oct 4th).  Following the new-repo creation steps I got as far as `git push -u origin master` before getting this error:

```
fatal: '/data/repositories/f/nw/fc/99/71/2513598/2513598.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I confirmed that my project's .git directory was normal.  Having confusion, I deleted the folder and started again (thinking that I had perhaps missed a step, fat-fingered something, etc), but came up to the same problem.

To ensure that my account wasn't broken, I tried cloning, pulling, and pushing repos, and found that they were working well.

Finally I went to my repo page and saw this:

[image]

Waiting...

Waiting...

Cut to yesterday morning with no change, I went to delete the repo on GitHub but noticed that on this error page, the Admin button is not available.  Finally I sent an email to support@github.com with all of this info (and the repo name & location, naturally), but now (a day later) have yet to receive anything.  I've checked that it's not in Spam.

At this point, I've worked around it, but I want to delete this unusable repo.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get in touch with GitHub?

Comment: I'd say https://github.com/contact ;-) Or book a flight to SF and don't forget your baseball bat.

Comment: Thanks @mailq , but I tried the first.  This problems isn't big enough for the second.  Perhaps if it was making me fail more...

Comment: needs to contact vendor / product owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly what finally worked was to gripe on Twitter.  I got a reply from @githubhelp asking me to resend my original email.